# Can't display time user has entered

Tags: java, android, android-activity, datepicker, fragment

So I've got a time picker all set up, and it opens just fine in my app. I can select the time, hit 'done', and it closes just like it's supposed to. I now want to take the time I entered and display it in a TextView that is defined in an XML file.

The closest I've gotten to doing this is by using this line of code:

```
TextView textView = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.timeOfWorkoutTextView);
```

This code at least doesn't show an error in Eclipse, but every time I run the app and hit the 'done' button, it throws an error and closes the app. Below is the LogCat:

```
04-27 19:13:49.482: E/AndroidRuntime(11553): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-27 19:13:49.482: E/AndroidRuntime(11553): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-27 19:13:49.482: E/AndroidRuntime(11553):    at com.example.test_project.TimePickerFragment.onTimeSet(TimePickerFragment.java:30)
04-27 19:13:49.482: E/AndroidRuntime(11553):    at android.app.TimePickerDialog.tryNotifyTimeSet(TimePickerDialog.java:130)
04-27 19:13:49.482: E/AndroidRuntime(11553):    at android.app.TimePickerDialog.onClick(TimePickerDialog.java:115)
04-27 19:13:49.482: E/AndroidRuntime(11553):    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
04-27 19:13:49.482: E/AndroidRuntime(11553):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-27 19:13:49.482: E/AndroidRuntime(11553):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-27 19:13:49.482: E/AndroidRuntime(11553):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5059)
04-27 19:13:49.482: E/AndroidRuntime(11553):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-27 19:13:49.482: E/AndroidRuntime(11553):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-27 19:13:49.482: E/AndroidRuntime(11553):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
04-27 19:13:49.482: E/AndroidRuntime(11553):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
04-27 19:13:49.482: E/AndroidRuntime(11553):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-27 19:13:51.060: I/Process(11553): Sending signal. PID: 11553 SIG: 9
```

I was planning on using StringBuilder to create a string that contains the hour and minute, and then use that like this: textView.setText(hourMinuteString);

Here is all of my code:

```
package com.example.test_project;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Use the current time as the default values for the picker
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

// Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
}

public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
TextView textView = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.timeOfWorkoutTextView);

}

public void showTimePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
}
}
```

I'm very new to Android Dev and programming in general, so some very detailed, stupid-enough-for-a-child-to-understand answers would be greatly appreciated!!!!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

override `onActivityCreated()` and initialize your text there, e.g.:

```
private TextView view;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState){
  view = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.timeOfWorkoutTextView);
}
```

Then modify `onTimeSet` to use `view` instead of calling `getView()`

```
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
  TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.timeOfWorkoutTextView);
}
```

Comment: So after trying out your suggestions I still get the same NullPointerException Error... played around with it for another hour, still not getting it!

Comment: In which line exactly is the exception? you can update your question modified code and LogCat with new StackTrace